# Why ConcurrentHashMap calculate hashcode with 0x7fffffff in 1.8?

Tags: java, hashcode, concurrenthashmap

When to calculate key's hashcode, spread() method is called:

```
static final int spread(int h) {
    return (h ^ (h >>> 16)) & HASH_BITS;
}
```

where `HASH_BITS` equals `0x7fffffff`, so, what is the purpose of `HASH_BITS`? Some one says it make the sign bit to 0, I am not sure about that.

Comment: It does indeed make the sign bit zero. Are you unsure whether this is the case, or whether that's the reason for using it?

Comment: @jsheeran Thanks for your answer, what I am confused is the reason for using it, because when calculate hashcode in ConcurrentHashMap is (h ^ (h >>> 16)) & 0x7fffffff but in 
 HashMap is (h ^ (h >>> 16)), it seems that 0x7fffffff is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

The `index` of KV Node in hash buckets is calculated by following formula:

```
index = (n - 1) & hash
```

- `hash` is the result of `spread()`
- `n` is the length of hash buckets which maximum is 2^30

  `private static final int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;`

So the maximum of `n - 1` is 2^30 - 1 which means the top bit of `hash` will never be used in index calculation.

But i still don't understand is it necessary to clear the top bit of `hash` to 0.It seems that there are more reasons to do so.

```
/**
 * Spreads (XORs) higher bits of hash to lower and also forces top
 * bit to 0. Because the table uses power-of-two masking, sets of
 * hashes that vary only in bits above the current mask will
 * always collide. (Among known examples are sets of Float keys
 * holding consecutive whole numbers in small tables.)  So we
 * apply a transform that spreads the impact of higher bits
 * downward. There is a tradeoff between speed, utility, and
 * quality of bit-spreading. Because many common sets of hashes
 * are already reasonably distributed (so don't benefit from
 * spreading), and because we use trees to handle large sets of
 * collisions in bins, we just XOR some shifted bits in the
 * cheapest possible way to reduce systematic lossage, as well as
 * to incorporate impact of the highest bits that would otherwise
 * never be used in index calculations because of table bounds.
 */
static final int spread(int h) {
    return (h ^ (h >>> 16)) & HASH_BITS;
}
```

Comment: There is indeed no clear explanation about the usage of HASH_BITS, it seems that it still works even without & HASH_BITS.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is to avoid collision with the preserved hashcodes: MOVED(-1), TREEBIN(-2) and RESERVED(-3) of which symbol bits are always 1.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, considering that `HASH_BITS` is declared directly after these constants, and commented with `// usable bits of normal node hash` ...